# Exclude IP with slash number on Google Analytics

Tags: filter

Argghh!!! How do I exclude an Ip with a slash from Google Analytics?

I was given this for this the IP with a slash and number: XXX.XXX.XX.XX/XX

Not sure how to set up this filter

I have tried this:

Filter Type: custom filter
Exclude
Filter Field: IP address
Filter Pattern: XXX.XXX.XX.XX/XX
Case Sensitive: No

Then there are views. Do I Apply Filter to Views?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To exclude internal traffic from appearing in a report view, create a custom filter to exclude a specific IP address or a range of IP addresses.

Filter Type: Custom > Exclude

Filter Field: Visitor IP Address

Filter Pattern:

For example, if the single IP address is `176.168.1.1`, then enter `176\.168\.1\.1`.

For example, if the range of IP addresses is 176.168.1.1-25 and 10.0.0.1-14, then enter
`^176\.168\.1\.([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])$|^10\.0\.0\.([1-9]|1[0-4])$`

Hope this helps.

Comment: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/the-slash-after-an-ip-address-cidr-notation This should give you a better understanding of what a slash means in networking terms.

Answer (score -1):

This site converts CIDR to regex for use in IP filtering.
https://d-fault.nl/cidrtoregex

Here is an article about it:
https://learnwebanalytics.com/can-i-use-cidr-notation-in-google-analytics/